# WAMP #1045 - Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, windows-7

I'm getting this error when trying to run any sql statement in mysql, like grant or select and I am on the administrator account. (i can access phpadmin and mysql consoles.) I've seen many discussions on this question, but answers are not relevant for my configuration
I installed standard wamp for windows 7 and mysql version is 5.6.12.

After struggling over 2 days I gave up and instead installed IIS, mysql and php individually, so this is not a current problem for myself. That took only a couple hours and all is working fine. Actually IIS seems preferable to apache since it is native and windows and more secure.

Thanks
Alan